# getting data with JSON in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have problem about getting data using JSON in android :
the Nonplus matter is : the code was work with another url but it does not work with my [url](http://monem.site88.net/SeleAvaHos.php) 
 , I have get data from server like this pic
[json data with php from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDgxO.jpg)

and android code

all metter in ( jArray = new JSONArray(result1) )  it doesn't work & get's exception with my case ......

```
    JSONObject json_data=null;
        try {

            jArray = new JSONArray(result1);


            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {


                     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = json_data.getString("name");
                String specializes = json_data.getString("type");
                String info = json_data.getString("type");
                String address = json_data.getString("address");
                String email = json_data.getString("email");
                double x_position = json_data.getDouble("position_x");
                double y_position = json_data.getDouble("position_y");
                int phone = json_data.getInt("telephone");
                }


            result2 = jArray.toString()+ "";   } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this is php code

```html
<?php

require "database2.php";


//$Desname=  $_POST["DesaseName"];
$Desname= "Apoplexy";

$r[]='';
$mysgl_query = "SELECT * FROM desases  as t1 LEFT JOIN `departments` as t2 
ON `department_id` = dep_id and desase_name = 'Apoplexy'
LEFT JOIN hospital_info as t3 ON `hosid` = `id` ;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysgl_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $r[]=$row;
}   
   
print(json_encode($r));
          


?>
```

Comment: Your JSON Array looks invalid. It should only contain an "array" of JSON Objects inside it. But in your JSON Array, it has invalid data " " inside an array .

Comment: Your json format is wrong

Comment: Yes you are right mr.Weava and mr.siddhesh,
 I solf it , 
Thank you alot  ..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to create json

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: ooooooooooh mr.siddhesh , you are amaaaaaaaaaaaaazing , 
I was spending about 2 days working behind this problem ..
just add : $rows = array();  make it running directly ......
thank you thank you ...!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the java code loop statement, why the condition is 'i < jArray.length() - 1', it will lost the last element of array.